# WCF web http Service doesnt return xmlns

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I have created a simple **REST** web service.. Responses are like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTableCategories xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

using this attribute

[XmlSerializerFormat]

However I see no `xmlns` there... like tempuri...

but when try to make a request I get 400 error if I don't define `xmlns="http://tempuri.org"` at root element..

Any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Is that the full response from the service call?  It probably isn't, so look inside of the soap elements inside of the full XML response and see what you come up with.

Comment: Can you post your definition of ArrayOfTableCategories?

Comment: ArrayOfTableCategories is automaticaly generated. It is List<TableCategories> .TableCategories is poco doesnt event have [Serialization]. Also it is a Rest service , so no soap!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as in your last 2 questions.

We have often seen that a WCF service is not able to have a List as a return parameter.

Follow the answer that I gave in this question: [Cannot deserialize with XMLSerializer result from WCF webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178687/cannot-deserialize-with-xmlserializer-result-from-wcf-webservice)